# Convert a JSON file to an OBJ file

Tags: json, object

After scrounging across the internet for a long time but coming no closer to my goal than before, I decided to bring the question here.

How can I Convert a JSON file to an OBJ file? Many of the of the other websites I found either didn't work or were for converting it the other way. To help, [Here](http://pastebin.com/Qts3UAds) is the file I am trying to convert (JSON). I am unexperienced with this so please bear with me if I ask too many questions. TIA, Jake

Comment: I won't be able to answer but you should at least tell us from where you are trying to do this conversion, answers will be different if you want to do it in C, in java, in javascript or by hand.

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry. Preferably C or Java but I can work with whatever is easiest.